# Solving $dP/dt = P(t)(1-P(t)/e^{2t})$ using $P(t) = 1/v(t)$ as a substitute

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Basically, I tried solving $dP/dt = P(t)(1-P(t)/e^{2t})$ using $P(t) = 1/v(t)$ as a substitute, and got $P(t)=-e^{2t}+ce^t$ (where $c$ is a real constant). I got here by deriving the substitution and use of the chain rule with the initial equation, but my answer isn't the same as my calculators answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I meant v(t)=1/P(t) as a substitute (not that it changes anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't dug into your substitution, but here's the approach I'd use instead
$$
P' = P-P^2e^{-2t} \\
P'-P = -P^2e^{-2t} \\
P'e^{-t} - P e^{-t} = -P^2e^{-2t} e^{-t} \\
\left(Pe^{-t} \right)' = - \left(P e^{-t}\right)^2 e^{-t}
$$
Do a substitution $V = Pe^{-t}$, then
$$
V' = -V^2 e^{-t} \\
-\frac {dV}{V^2} = e^{-t}dt \\
\frac 1V = -e^{-t} + C \\
V = \frac 1{C-e^{-t}} = \frac {e^t}{Ce^t-1}
$$
Do backward substitution
$$
P = \frac {e^{2t}}{Ce^{t}-1}
$$

### PS

I've checked with Mathematica on my computer and solution looks fine.